# What does the “test result indicator” indicate on a cockpit voice recorder?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, commercial-aviation, commercial-operations, cockpit-voice-recorder

I am really curious as to what the “green/red” strip of led indicate and the numbers below it. Having read around the web, i speculated that it could be an audio quality rating scale. Would help alot of someone could please help explain the “numbers” and why there is so many led blocks on the strip...[image]

Comment: There are a number of different CVR models out there, which one is this specifically?

Comment: Looks like a newer Airbus CVR panel. The test button generates an internal low frequency test tone signal and the LED will tell you the quality of the audio picked up by the CVR when the tone is generated. The tone is internal and can only be heard if you plug in a headset into the headset jack. A good test will indicate in the green, the more green, the better the test result. On the A320 the tone is heard over the cockpit speakers.

Comment: @RonBeyer i am not too sure about the model, but its from A330-300

Comment: @JuanJimenez By any chance do you know the meaning of the “numbers” below the strip? 0.3-1.15? So could you say, a new plane (if tested on the CVR) would get a full green led on the strip?

Comment: I have not been able to find any other example of a panel with the numbers, let alone an explanation. Sorry. I am also not 100% sure of the details, which is why I posted as a comment and not an answer. But if I had to guess, the numbers may be referring to the measurement of the frequency of the tone and how it compares to what the ideal measurement should be. But that is only an educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the exact model you showed, but the A330 and A340 FCOM on [SmartCockpit](http://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/A330-Communications.pdf) shows a similar one. Unfortunately the description of the test is rather short:

[image: A330 FCOM CVR]

The Overhead Pushbutton explanation on [SmartCockpit](http://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/A330-A340_Overhead_Pushbuttons.pdf) is equally short:

[image: A330 Overhead Pushbutton Explanation]

My best guess would be that it shows the recorded volume from low on the left to high on the right and it is considered OK (test passed) if it reaches into the green LEDs, therefore making sure the CVR can pick up voices clearly enough. *I hope someone working with these CVRs can provide a more accurate answer!*